# JavaScript Undefined Variable Error In IE6

Tags: php, internet-explorer, variables, undefined

I have a PHP file in that I have declared a JavaScript variable.

I will get that variable value while I am opening the page directly by type the my URL on IE6.

But the problem is if I am clicking a `href` link to open the same page got particular variable undefined error on IE6.

After undefined error if I refresh the same page I can get the variable value.

I am using script tag to load the page

as like

```
<script language="javascript" src="commonjs.php"></script>
```

In my commonjs.php

```
<?  include_once("myconffile.php");  ?>
var myvars = <?=$varConfValue['domainname']?>
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: Are  you sure `short_open_tag` is enabled? Afaik, by default it is not.

Comment: yes its enabled and if i refresh the same page i can get the value for same variable after got the undefined error.

Comment: Are you sure you have cleaned the browser cache?

Answer (score 2):

You should add quotes around the value of `myvars` if it is a string.

```
<?  include_once("myconffile.php");  ?>
 var myvars = "<?=$varConfValue['domainname']?>"
```

Otherwise you get something like `var myvars = localhost`. Javascript then looks for a variable named `localhost`, which is undefined.

Comment: Thanks naivists, In my original file i used quotes. Here i missed to mention it. please advise if any other.